# How to break listing to pages in latex?

Tags: latex, listings

I'm trying to split my listing into several pages, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I have read it should work automatically if you set `breaklines=true`. I can't. Is there another option without creating multiple listings?

```
    \lstset{numbers=left,
    columns=fullflexible,
    stepnumber=1,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\color{lineNumberColor}\tiny,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    showtabs=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    tabsize=4,
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{pred}\hookrightarrow\space}},
    commentstyle=\slshape\color{commentColor},
    keywordstyle=\color{keywordColor}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{stringColor}\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: It's set, but the page doesn't break.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to specify where a new page starts in your listing, you can do that using the `escapeinside` option. The `breaklines` option ensures line wraps to fit the page horizontally when set to true.

By specifying ``` escapeinside=`` ``` , you can escape the listings context between two backtics (`` ` ``). To break a line you can insert `\newpage` between the backticks like so:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=``]
    page 1

    `\newpage`

    page 2
\end{lstlisting}
```

The listing should be split up into two pages with `page 1` written on one page and `page 2` written on the next one.

Comment: What if you *don't* know where you want the page break to occur, and you want LaTeX to calculate it automatically?